# MySQL: Select last from group, but with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have the following table:

```
name     created_for created_on            status
jen      2012-05-27  2012-02-15 12:14:09    Y
joe      2012-10-01  2012-02-15 12:22:09    Y
bob      2012-10-01  2012-02-15 12:47:09    N
jim      2012-10-01  2012-02-24 12:47:09    N
jim      2012-10-01  2012-02-29 12:47:09    Y
sam      2012-10-01  2012-03-11 12:47:09    N
sam      2012-10-01  2012-03-15 12:47:09    C
sam      2012-10-01  2012-03-22 12:47:09    Y
tom      2012-10-01  2012-04-10 12:47:09    N
tom      2012-10-01  2012-04-11 12:47:09    N
```

What I want to return is the last row of name, created_on for each person that has a created_for date of 2012-10-01, but ONLY IF the status for that last entry is an N. So for the table above, I want to get back:

```
name     created_on
bob      2012-02-15 12:47:09
tom      2012-04-11 12:47:09
```

The status condition is what's throwing me. I can't seem to figure out where to place the "where status='N'" to get the right results.

Comment: What's the query you're currently using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM
 (
    SELECT name, MAX(created_on) MaxDate
    FROM YourTableName
    GROUP BY name
  ) t1 INNER JOIN YourTableName t2  on t1.name    = t2.name 
                                   AND t1.MaxDate = t2.created_on
 WHERE t2.created_for = '2012-10-01'
   AND t2.status = 'N'
```

Comment: That works for the subset of the table above but as soon as I add another row like: `bob 2012-10-04 2012-07-07 12:12:12 N` bob is no longer returned for 2012-10-01
@mahmoud-gamal

Comment: @Jim Thats because the record you added `bob 2012-10-04 2012-07-07 12:12:12 N` has the `created_for` field = `2012-10-04` not `2012-10-01` there for isn't returned because of the condition `WHERE t2.created_for = '2012-10-01'`

Comment: No, look again. It no longer returns bob FOR 2012-10-01. With the table subset I posted, it returns the 2 rows wanted. However, if I add that addition row for Bob with a later date, only 1 row is returned. The bob row for 2012-10-01 is no longer returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select name, max(created_on) max_created_on
    from MyTable
    where created_for = '2012-10-01'
    group by name
) tm on t.name = tm.name and t.created_on = tm.max_created_on
where t.status = 'N'
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1abd1/7)